# Code Coverage issue for my scheduled class

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex

In have been written a schedule apex class to send an email to users where the opportunity not modified by 14 days, the class is working fine I am writing the test class which it is not covering the code coverage. Please help me to cover the test class.
The apex class and test class is given below.

Class:

```
public class YODA_YCN_Schedule_NoActionEmail implements Schedulable {
  public void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
    YODA_YCN_Schedule_NoActionEmail.sendYCNEmail();
  }
  public static boolean isTestRunning = false;
  public static void sendYCNEmail() {
    Set<id> taskOppId = new Set<id>();
    try {
      List<Task> getTaskList = [
        SELECT WhatId
        FROM Task
        WHERE lastModifiedDate > Last_N_Days:14 AND What.type = 'Opportunity'
      ];
      List<Event> getEventList = [
        SELECT WhatId
        FROM Event
        WHERE lastModifiedDate > Last_N_Days:14 AND What.type = 'Opportunity'
      ];
      for (Task tsk : getTaskList) {
        taskOppId.add(tsk.WhatId);
      }
      for (Event evt : getEventList) {
        taskOppId.add(evt.WhatId);
      }
      List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
      if (!istestRunning) {
        oppList = [
          SELECT
            Id,
            Name,
            Owner.Id,
            Owner.Email,
            Owner.YCN_User_Line_Manager__c,
            Owner.Name,
            Region__c,
            Amount,
            closeDate,
            LastModifiedDate
          FROM Opportunity
          WHERE
            LastModifiedDate < Last_N_Days:14
            AND Id NOT IN :taskOppId
            AND StageName NOT IN ('Closed Won', 'Closed Lost')
            AND Region__c = 'YCN'
          ORDER BY LastModifiedDate
          LIMIT 10000
        ];
      } else {
        oppList = [
          SELECT
            id,
            name,
            Owner.id,
            Owner.email,
            Owner.YCN_User_Line_Manager__c,
            Owner.name,
            Region__c,
            Amount,
            closeDate,
            LastModifiedDate
          FROM opportunity
        ];
      }
      Map<id, List<Opportunity>> owenrOppMap = new Map<id, List<Opportunity>>();
      for (Opportunity opp : oppList) {
        if (!owenrOppMap.containsKey(opp.OwnerId)) {
          owenrOppMap.put(opp.OwnerId, new List<Opportunity>());
        }
        owenrOppMap.get(opp.OwnerId).add(opp);
      }
      List<OrgWideEmailAddress> orgWideAdd = [
        SELECT id
        FROM OrgWideEmailAddress
        WHERE Address = 'noreply@gmail.com'
      ];
      for (Id ownerId : owenrOppMap.keySet()) {
        List<Opportunity> ownerOpportunities = owenrOppMap.get(ownerId);
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        List<string> sendTo = new List<string>{
          string.valueof(ownerOpportunities[0].Owner.email)
        };
        List<string> ccTo = new List<String>();
        if (
          !string.isBlank(ownerOpportunities[0].Owner.YCN_User_Line_Manager__c)
        )
          emailAddresses = ownerOpportunities[0]
            .Owner.YCN_User_Line_Manager__c.split(',');
        Integer emailCounter = 0;
        for (String emailAddress : emailAddresses) {
          emailAddress = emailAddress.trim();
          ccTo.add(emailAddress);
          emailCounter++;
          if (emailCounter >= 2) {
            break;
          }
        }

        mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
        mail.setCcAddresses(ccTo);
        mail.setSubject('无更新提醒');
        mail.setCharset('UTF-8');
        mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressID(orgWideAdd[0].id);
        String body =
          '亲爱的' +
          ' ' +
          ownerOpportunities[0].Owner.name +
          ',' +
          '<br/><br/>';
        body +=
          '请注意，在过去 14 天内，以下业务机会记录没有任何更新:' +
          '<br/><br/>';
        String tableHtml = '<html><body>';
        tableHtml += '<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">';
        tableHtml += '<tr>';
        tableHtml += '<th style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px;">业务机会名称</th>';
        tableHtml += '<th style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px;">机会所有者</th>';
        tableHtml += '<th style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px;">金额</th>';
        tableHtml += '<th style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px;">关闭日期</th>';
        tableHtml += '<th style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px;">距上次更新的天数</th>';
        tableHtml += '</tr>';
        for (Opportunity opp : ownerOpportunities) {
          tableHtml += '<tr>';
          tableHtml +=
            '<td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px;"><a href="' +
            URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() +
            '/' +
            opp.id +
            '">' +
            opp.Name +
            '</a></td>';
          tableHtml +=
            '<td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px;">' +
            ownerOpportunities[0].Owner.name +
            '</td>';
          tableHtml +=
            '<td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px;">' +
            opp.Amount +
            '</td>';
          tableHtml +=
            '<td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px;">' +
            opp.CloseDate +
            '</td>';
          tableHtml +=
            '<td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px;">' +
            (Date.valueOf(opp.LastModifiedDate)).daysBetween(system.today()) +
            ' ' +
            '' +
            'Days' +
            '</td>';
          tableHtml += '</tr>';
        }
        tableHtml += '</table>';
        tableHtml += '</body></html>';
        body += +tableHtml + '<br/><br/>';
        body += 'Thank you.' + '<br/>';
        body += 'YODA 系统管理员';
        mail.setHtmlBody(body);
        mails.add(mail);
      }
      //Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email});
      Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
    } catch (exception e) {
      system.debug('Error' + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class YODA_YCN_Schedule_NoActionEmailTest {
  @testSetup
  static void setup() {
    List<User> userList = new List<User>();
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'];
    UserRole prntRole = new UserRole(Name = 'TestRole');
    insert prntRole;
    UserRole usrRole = new UserRole(
      Name = 'TestUserRole',
      parentroleId = prntRole.id
    );
    insert usrRole;
    User u = new user(
      ProfileId = p.Id,
      userroleid = usrRole.id,
      LastName = 'last',
      Username = 'TestUser@gmail.com' + System.currentTimeMillis(),
      CompanyName = 'TEST',
      Title = 'title',
      Alias = 'alias',
      TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
      EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
      LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
      LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
      Email = 'TestUser@gmail.com',
      Region__c = 'YCN',
      Division_BU__c = 'TM',
      YCN_User_Line_Manager__c = 'Test@gmail.com,Test1@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com,test3@gmail.com'
    );
    User u1 = new user(
      ProfileId = p.Id,
      userroleid = prntRole.id,
      LastName = 'last',
      Username = 'TestUser1@gmail.com' + System.currentTimeMillis(),
      CompanyName = 'TEST',
      Title = 'title',
      Alias = 'alias',
      TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
      EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
      LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
      LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
      Email = 'TestUser1@gmail.com',
      Region__c = 'YCN',
      Division_BU__c = 'TM'
    );
    System.debug('Userlist' + userList);
    userList.add(u);
    userList.add(u1);
    insert userList;
  }

  @isTest
  public static void sendEmailTest() {
    user u = [
      SELECT name, email, region__c, Regional_BU__c, Subregion__c
      FROM user
      WHERE Email = 'TestUser@gmail.com'
      LIMIT 1
    ];
    System.runAs(u) {
      Account acc = YODA_TestAccountDataFactory.getAccount(
        'Test Account',
        false
      );
      insert acc;

      Contact con = new Contact(LastName = 'Test');
      insert con;
      List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
      opportunity opp = new opportunity(
        Name = 'TestOPP',
        CurrencyIsoCode = 'INR',
        StageName = 'Qualify(SQL)',
        GTT_Category_Of_Interest__c = 'Flow Meters',
        Amount = 3000,
        CloseDate = System.today() - 1,
        Contact__c = con.id,
        OwnerId = u.id,
        AccountId = acc.id,
        Yokogawa_Product_HQ__c = 'Yes'
      );
      oppList.add(opp);
      opportunity opp1 = new opportunity(
        Name = 'TestOPP1',
        CurrencyIsoCode = 'INR',
        StageName = 'Qualify(SQL)',
        GTT_Category_Of_Interest__c = 'Flow Meters',
        Amount = 3000,
        CloseDate = System.today() - 1,
        Contact__c = con.id,
        OwnerId = u.id,
        AccountId = acc.id,
        Yokogawa_Product_HQ__c = 'Yes'
      );
      oppList.add(opp1);
      insert oppList;
      Task tsk = new Task();
      tsk.subject = 'Test YCN';
      tsk.WhatId = opp1.id;
      tsk.Priority = 'Normal';
      insert tsk;
      Test.startTest();
      YODA_YCN_Schedule_NoActionEmail.isTestRunning = true;
      YODA_YCN_Schedule_NoActionEmail.sendYCNEmail();
      Test.stopTest();
    }

  }
  @isTest
  public static void testExecute() {
    // Test scheduling of the job and ensure it executes successfully
    Test.startTest();
    String jobId = System.schedule(
      'Test YCN Schedule',
      '0 0 0 * * ?',
      new YODA_YCN_Schedule_NoActionEmail()
    );
    Test.stopTest();
    System.assertNotEquals(null, jobId);
  }
}
```

Please help me to cover the code.

Thanks

Comment: I reformatted your code to make it more legible, but please be aware that there was a syntax error in the code you pasted. `[select id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'noreply@gmail.com'` was missing `];` at the end, so the latest version may not be deployed properly. Please doublecheck the code. Aside from that, what is your code coverage problem? What lines are not being covered?

Comment: Thanks for responding 
My code coverage is 45%, the lines not covering below.
 From the line  mail.setToAddresses(sendTo); and rest of the below lines

Comment: BTW, you should avoid converting a User to an email address when sending the email as this means the email consumes your daily limits. If you use `setTargetObjectId` with a user ID you avoid this consumption.